# Почему метод класса не правильно выводит данные?

Tags: c++

Создаю класс TimeSpan, суть которого преобразовать веденное в секундах время в дату. Но почему он выводит не верные данные, в чем ошибка?

.hpp
namespace lab1 {

```
class TimeSpan {

  private:
    int days = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    int timeInSeconds = 0;

  public:
    TimeSpan() = default;
    TimeSpan(int timeInSeconds);
    ~TimeSpan() = default;

    void secondTransferFromData(int timeInSeconds);
    void setTime(int timeInSeconds);
    int getDays();
};
```

}

.cpp

```
#include "Timespan.hpp"

namespace time {

    TimeSpan::TimeSpan(int timeInSeconds) {
        setTime(timeInSeconds);
    }

   void TimeSpan::secondTransferFromData(int timeInSeconds) {
       
       days = timeInSeconds / 24 * 60 * 60;
       hours = (timeInSeconds - days * 24 * 60 * 60) / 60 * 60;
       minutes = (timeInSeconds - days * 24 * 60 * 60 - hours * 60 * 60) / 60;
       seconds = (timeInSeconds - days * 24 * 60 * 60 - hours * 60 * 60 - minutes * 60);
    }

    void TimeSpan::setTime(int timeInSeconds) {
        secondTransferFromData(timeInSeconds);
    }

    int TimeSpan::getDays() {
        return days;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Timespan.hpp"
using namespace lab1;

int main() {

    lab1::TimeSpan Time = TimeSpan(200000);
    int days = Time.getDays();
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

В чем ошибка? Только начинаю постигать ООП.

Comment: Правило трех/пяти? (если добавили пользовательские конструкторы, будьте добры дописать конструкторы копирования, операторы присваивания и так далее)

Comment: То есть проблема в отсутствии конструктора копирования и прочее? Почему выводит совершенно не те числа?

Comment: наверно, просто больше по Вашему примеру не понять. Но я не исключаю, что там есть ещё много кода, который делает много чего.

Comment: Нет, это весь код. Пока хотел проверить как хотя бы на начальном этапе работает, и поэтому сделал геттер дней

Comment: я попробовал поиграть с Вашим кодом - он работает ожидаемо для меня. Но мне пришлось исправить строку `std::cout << a << std::endl;` - иначе оно не компилируется. Поэтому, я считаю, что там части кода нет

Comment: Видимо я пока не понимаю, как должен выглядеть полноценный класс. Я хотел, чтобы подав на конструктор число секунд и затем вызвав метод getDays, я получил число дней содержащихся в 200 000 секундах

Comment: Нашел ошибку, не поставил скобки в арифметических операциях